# DSLR setting for a good contrast, sharper picture?

Tags: sharpness, contrast

Is there any specific setting for capturing a picture that has a good contrast and is sharp? Sometimes I get a low contrast and need to go for post processing. I'm a beginner in DSLR photography and my  camera is Nikon D5200. I  hope this is not a camera specific question and I'm willing to widen my knowledge for taking a good photo.

Thanks in advance :-)

Update:

[image: Low contast picture]

Comment: Can you post a link to an example picture?

Comment: Maybe see: [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Comment: @Barn Added an example pic from the web.

Comment: The image you posted is not really a photo. It could be a picture of painting or a heavily processed image. No camera should produce something like this directly. Do a full reset if it does then post a JPEG photo directly from the camera to see if there are truly any issues.

Comment: on reading the link by @inkista one of the culprit might be 18-55mm kit lens. But yes, I get few pic like the one shown above.

Comment: Can you include some EXIF information? (iso, aperture, shutter speed), as well as what the image looked like before post-processing?

Comment: @MnZ, actually, one of the things I say in that link is that the 18-55 _isn't_ going to be the problem, so much as how you use it. :)

Comment: Yep I get it :) . I will update with the EXIF infos soon.

Comment: Shot through a window? Low contrast is often a problem when shooting through windows, screens, even chain-link fences.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely post processed (in camera or out) to add posterization. No lens is going to turn gradient colors into solids like that.

Try either changing modes or resetting your camera to factory settings.

Comment: Should the #1 rule be "read the notice" before asking ?