# will the Panasonic Lumix G7 be good for entry level photography?

Tags: dslr, mirrorless

I got a deal which I seem to think it's a great one. someone is selling me a Lumix G7 for $200? is that even good? I checked the price on amazon is cost around $400+ so I'm thinking it will be good for $200 I think is a good deal. the thing is that I'm really into streetwear photograpy and do you guys think this will be a good camera to shoot photos? I currently use a nikon D3200 because like i said... I am a beginner at photography and I personally think it'll be better but I'm not 100% sure... can I get some opinions?

Comment: What about the D3200 is holding you back? If you can't answer that, don't buy anything.

Comment: I feel like the quality of the picture is not good enough with the D3200... I take pics and they come out all grainy and yes I've tried different settings different lighting, etc

Comment: What lens are you using on your nikon camera? And are you taking photos in sunlight or some other light.

Comment: As Philip said above, first find out what is the problem with your current gear; than you can find either a different lens/camera or accessory that fits your need, whether it is another camera (system) or just an accessory (lens/flasher etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Comment: What, if any, lenses are included in the deal? What lenses are you currently using with the D3300?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lumix G7 has a tiny micro four thirds sensor, which has 2x crop factor.

Your Nikon D3200 has a small Nikon crop sensor, which has 1.5x crop factor.

All other things being equal, the G7 will take **worse** pictures that are **more grainy** due to the smaller sensor.

However, all other things are not equal. Lumix G7 was released in 2015 and D3200 in 2012. So, the 3 years of development in sensors can overcome some of the drawbacks of the larger crop factor. At least Lumix G7 goes to ISO 25600 while D3200 goes only to ISO 6400. That might be an indication that the G7 could handle the noise better. But then again, a Nikon released in 2015 would probably be at least as good (if not better) than a micro four thirds camera released in 2015.

I have a few suggestions you can do to improve your photography with D3200:

- First of all, check what JPG compression settings you use. The graininess may be a too high compression level set in the camera.
- Buy a faster lens. The kit lens has a small aperture, which is not suitable for low-light photograpy. A prime? A fast zoom? (Ok, fast zooms may be expensive but some third party manufacturers can supply them for cheaper prices, but then again you are always taking a risk with third party lenses.)
- Buy an external flash and use it. Adding more light will make images less grainy.
- If your lens has image stabilization, turn it on, lower the shutter speed and lower the ISO as well. However, this won't help for moving targets.
- Buy a tripod. That allows you to use lower shutter speeds and thus lower ISO sensitivity. However, it won't help for moving targets.
- Go through all of your camera menus and see if you can find an adjustable noise reduction setting. Use it!
- Shoot RAW and use RawTherapee to remove the graininess/noise from the image. It has an adjustable slider for that.
- Learn to accept that some grain in the image is inevitable. We didn't have grain free images with high-ISO films, either. Remove the chroma noise as well as you can and leave most of the luma noise / grain there.

The trend with mirrorless seems to be towards larger sensor sizes. I'd suggest not investing significant amounts of money into the micro four thirds system with its huge 2x crop, as it could very well be one of the first victims of declining camera sales.

If you don't know what exactly in your equipment is limiting you, it's not the time to upgrade your camera body. Especially, it's not the time to switch from one system (Nikon crop) to another (micro four thirds). And most people switch systems by going to larger sensor size, so you're going against the trend if you choose micro four thirds.

Comment: Just because a camera is released at time X does not mean the sensor used was developed for that camera. It's quite possible a camera is released using older sensor tech, especially if we're talking about prosumer/consumer grades.

Comment: I'm not sure "tiny" is a fair label for the 4/3rds sensor. It's still many times larger than for example a typical cell phone camera.

Comment: There's less difference between µ4/3 and APS-C than there is between APS-C and FF.